# How do I make a registration link in a Wordpress plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a Wordpress plugin, WP User Frontend, in which you need to be logged in to use it. If you attempt to use it while not logged in you get a message:

> This page is restricted. Please Login to view this page.

where "Login" is a link.

I would like to change the message to:

> Please Register to view this page

in HTML:

```
<h3><a href="http://example.com/wp-login.php?action=register">Register</a>Please  to view this page.</h3>
```

where "register" is a link to the registration page, not the login page.

I tried changing this code:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $this->post_form( $post_type );
} else {
    printf( __( "This page is restricted. Please %s to view this page.", 'wpuf' ), wp_loginout( get_permalink(), false ) );
}
```

to

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $this->post_form( $post_type );
} else {
    printf( __( "Please %s to view this page.", 'wpuf' ), wp_register('', '') );
}
```

But the result on the page is :

```
RegisterPlease to view this page.
```

The Register link is before the rest of the String.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Is the HTML produced valid? What does `echo __( "Please %s to view this page.", 'wpuf' );` produce?

Comment: Added HTML to question

Comment: I think you added it to the wrong place. What about the second part of my question?

Comment: It produces: Please %s to view this page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the third argument that controls **output**. The [API documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register) outlines the signature for this method. The reason for the weird output is that **wp_register** is calling **echo** during the function call.

```
wp_register('', '', false);
```